# Inverse of a large sparse matrix in Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, markov-chains, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

**Background:** Let $\Omega$ be the state space of an absorbing Markov chain with $\Omega_a$ being the set of absorbing states, and its complement $\Omega_a^c$, being the set of transient states. The infinitesimal generator matrix $Q$ of this Markov chain in the canonical form is:
\begin{align}
Q_=
  \begin{array}{c|cc}
       & \Omega_a  & \Omega_a^c \\
    \hline
    \Omega_a   & 0 & 0 \\
    \Omega_a^c & W_1 & W_2 \\
  \end{array}
  .\label{kao}
\end{align}
Based on the theory of Markov chain, $W_2$ is inverse-negative. That is,  $W_2^{-1}$ exists and all of its elements are negative.

**My Problem:** For a problem that I am dealing with, I use Matlab to calculate   $W_2^{-1}$. When my state space is small, it works as expected, however, when my state space is large (> 15000) Matlab fails to calculate the inverse correctly and gives me an inverse that has positive elements (note that all elements of the inverse matrix have to be negative theoretically, but some elements turn out to be in the order of $10^{12}$) and even $W_2 * W_2^{-1} \neq I$. I wonder if someone can suggest an efficient way of calculating the inverse of large matrices.

Here is how I calculate the inverse in Matlab: as $W_2$ is highly sparse, I use the following line of command (note that I avoid using inv($W_2$)):

inverse = sparse($W_2$)\sparse(eye(size($W_2$)));

You can download the .dat file of my matrix $W_2$ from my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r8uChhNYWoVpr7qipVeYo7lk-R1C4pcg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: `inv(X)` is equivalent to `X\speye(size(X))` when `X` is sparse.

Comment: I downloaded your matrix. MATLAB's function condest estimates that the 2-norm condition number is 2.610e19. This suggests that you cannot compute an accurate inverse using *naive* IEEE double precision arithmetic. Rather it is necessary to emulate a smaller unit roundoff. Regardless, I computed $B=W2\speye(size(W2))$. The entries were all negative and were in the interval between -5.4621e12 and -1.1860e-74. This is good, but not what you reported. However, the Frobenius norm relative residual is 5.6121, i.e., indicating that the inverse has not be computed accurately.

Comment: Thanks for experimenting with the matrix. I tried both sparse(W2)\speye(size(W2)) and W2\speye(size(W2)). While these two are supposed to give the same result, interestingly, I get positive elements in the inverse matrix obtained from the first formula, but not from the second one! (which confirms the contradiction between my original report and yours.) I believe all these contradictions happen because the calculations are not stable. You mentioned that it is "necessary to emulate a smaller unit roundoff." Would you please provide more details on this? Or refer me to a reference? Thanks.

Comment: This [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jjiam/1265033781) is a good place to start. Siegfried Rump has written many papers on extra accurate algorithms. The central key-word is "error-free transformations". Before you begin studying this work you must be certain that you absolutely need an accurate inverse matrix. It is possible that you can make do with a library that implements arbitrary precision arithmetic, say, 200 significant figures.

Comment: Note: When I comment on your question, you are automatically notified. However, when you comment on your question you must use @username to trigger notification. I only saw your question because I checked manually.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for the note and the comment. I do not need arbitrary precision arithmetic. Even 16 significant figures would be enough for me as long as the inverse is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert with Matlab but when you call upon the inv() function it applies different methods depending upon the structure of your Matrix. I'm guessing that you're looking to form an Eigenvalue Decomposition for your Markov Chain Matrix. I would recommend that you first check the Eigenvalues for $W_2$, following that it's non-degenerate that you check that your $W_2$ is properly formed and structured.

Finally, it may be that your Matrix is sound and non-degenerate but that computationally it's unstable and difficult to compute the inverse. In that case, I would ask exactly what you are going to use the inverse for? if it's to solve a Matrix System, then instead of computing the inverse that it's better to script an algorithm to solve the system you are working with.